# How to specify [any symbol] in SED?

Tags: text-processing, sed, character-encoding

I am using the SED command to strip out foreign language and other non-keyboard characters from very large text files:

example:

```
sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]//g'
```

The above command keeps any line that contains only alpha-numeric characters, which is close to what I want. The problem is that it also strips away any lines that contain common symbols like !@#$% and so on. I want to keep those. I tried searching for a bullion command something like !-), or something. But I could not find anything like that.

So how do I filter out Arabic an Russian and untype-able characters from my lists? (ideally, I don't want to just nuke the character, I want to nuke the whole line where its found.)

Comment: To remove lines, you should use `grep -v` instead of `sed`.

Comment: Foreign to whom? What's your script, keyboard layout or language? English? Which one? US English, London English, Scottish English. Are `$`, `£`, `€` "foreign" to you for instance?

Comment: Also note that your `[a-z]` generally matches on characters such as `ɘəɚɛɜɝɞɟɠɡɢɣɤɥɦɧɨɩɪɫɬɭɮɯɰɱ` (and hundreds more) which many English speakers would consider "foreign".

Answer (score 1):

To remove non-ASCII characters from a text, consider using `tr` like so:

```bsh
LC_ALL=C tr -d -c '[:print:][:cntrl:]' <file.in >file.out
```

The two POSIX character classes `[:print:]` and `[:cntrl:]` together span all characters in the ASCII range, and with `-c` we ask `tr` to consider the complement set to this, i.e. all non-ASCII characters. With `-d` we ask `tr` to delete characters in that complement set.

We set `LC_ALL` to `C` (or `POSIX`) to have `[:print:]` character class match only the characters in the ASCII range 32 to 126. Otherwise it may match printable characters in the local locale, such as `ä`. The class `[:cntrl:]` matches characters in the range 0 to 31, and 127.  With `LC_ALL=C`, these two classes together cover 0 through to 127, which are the ASCII characters.

To remove whole lines that contain any non-ASCII characters:

```bsh
LC_ALL=C grep -v '[^[:print:][:cntrl:]]' <file.in >file.out
```

The expression `[^[:print:][:cntrl:]]` would match a single non-ASCII character. With `-v` we ask `grep` to extract all lines *not* matching that expression, i.e. to extract lines that don't contain any non-ASCII characters.

These two commands could also be done with `sed`:

Remove non-ASCII characters:

```bsh
LC_ALL=C sed 's/[^[:print:][:cntrl:]]//g' <file.in >file.out
```

Remove lines with non-ASCII characters:

```bsh
LC_ALL=C sed '/[^[:print:][:cntrl:]]/d' <file.in >file.out
```

Note that, as Stéphane points out [in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/631390/how-to-specify-any-symbol-in-sed/631400?noredirect=1#comment1181666_631400), the above commands would give you a text back that contains only ASCII characters, *or at least characters encoded as ASCII* (depending on the encoding of the file).

---

A totally different approach would be to use `iconv`:

```bsh
iconv -c -t ascii file.in >file.out
```

This converts the file to ASCII encoding while silently dropping any characters (not lines) that couldn't be converted.

Comment: That assumes `file.in` is not encoded in charsets like BIG5, BIGHKSCS, GB18030, GBK which have characters whose encoding contains byte values in the 32-127 range.

Comment: Note that strictly speaking, `LC_ALL=C` doesn't imply "ASCII" (though in practice it does in the immense majority of ASCII-based systems (themselves being immensely majoritary), so it's good enough an approximation.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from using classes as Kusalananda does, you might also create your own range based on unicode. Check [this reference unicolde table](https://unicode-table.com/en/) for finding the characters you like. With PCRE a possible way of "standard" characters + TAB would be:

```
 grep -P '^[\x{0020}-\x{007e}\x{0008}]{1,}$' file
```

Note how newline `\x{000A}` is not included as control character, due to `grep`'s per-line functionality (in standard mode). Please consider that MS-style newlines would be affected and use `\x{000d}\x{000a}` for newlines!

Comment: Both CR and TAB are already in the `\x{0000}-\x{007e}` range. Why are you excluding `\x7F` and not the other ASCII control characters? Also note that it removes empty lines.

Comment: You may want to clarify what you mean by "standard" here. Unicode is a "standard" and covers all characters in existence. A "standard" charset limited to US English and many western Europe countries is ISO8859-15 (would include `é` already included by the OP's `[a-z]` for instance). ASCII is an old (from the 60s possibly earlier, initially  6bits, now 7bits) US-only charset but misses several of the characters now commonly used even in the US.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I specifically did not include this range, as e.g. AKN or BEL are not printable, a TAB or newline however clearly visible in a text, despite being control characters.  "standard" was meant to be as obscure as OP's (lack of) definition - hence the quotes and the referece to the table with a mere example range in the code. I expected OP to adapt.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Now I saw my error: The range was meant to start at `\x{0020}` not `\x{0000}`- corrected.

Comment: FF, VT, CR, BS for instance are about as "visible" as LF/TAB in text. When sent to a terminal, they move the cursor position as well. And like for TAB, the behaviour varies depending on the output device.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Fair enough, yet I am not sure if e.g. BS has a static way of being represented (TAB and VT sure do) when just displayed via `cat`, `more` or alike. The idea was to give an example and make OP decide on what should be included and to show that "range of unicode characters" could be a feasible (and pretty secure) way of achieving a specific set of characters.